# Set root of Aurelia router when using pushState

Tags: aurelia

Is there a way to set the root path of the router similar to Durandal?

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
this.router.configure(config => {
  config.title = 'Aurelia';
  config.options.pushState = true;
  config.options.root = '/root';
  config.map([
    { route: ['','welcome'],  moduleId: './welcome',      nav: true, title:'Welcome' }
  ]);
});
```

So that the url `http://example.com/root` maps to `welcome` module.

**EDIT**: I just realized the code works as expected. Something else is causing the problem. Anyway, the root property should be added to the documentation. I only knew about it because I've worked with Durandal before.

Comment: Can you open an issue in the router repository?

Comment: Did you get this resolved?

Answer (score 0):

You might try setting a base tag in the header of your html file

`<base href="http://www.example.com/root">`